# If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing in $(0,\infty)$, prove that $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for $a,b >0$

Tags: calculus

If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing in $(0,\infty)$, prove that $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for $a,b >0$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\dfrac{f(a+b)}{a+b} \leq \dfrac{f(a)}{a} \Rightarrow \dfrac{a}{a+b}\cdot f(a+b) \leq f(a)$, and $\dfrac{b}{a+b}\cdot f(a+b) \leq f(b)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: In general one should use $\Rightarrow$ (in TeX, $\texttt{\Rightarrow}$) to denote implication. The single arrow, $\to$ could be interpreted as, e.g., an assertion of a limiting value.